# Error Adding Child View on RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I having problems adding child views  after a running relative layout. What I know, when I add another view into the layout, I just place the xml code at the bottom of the last view on the layout. Then add the positioning.

**I want to add this code under rating bar:**

```
     <TextView        
        android:id="@+id/viewSeparat2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="2px" 
        android:background="#DADADA" />
```

**XML Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/separator"
        android:dividerPadding="12dip"
        android:showDividers="middle"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
         >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemItem"
        android:src="@drawable/content_picture"
        android:tag="image_item_grid_image"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:contentDescription="Desc"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPid"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparator"        
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textPid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSellingPrice"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textSellingPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addTOCart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/itemItem"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/add_to_cart" />

        <TextView        
            android:id="@+id/viewSeparator"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addTOCart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="2px" 
            android:background="#DADADA" />

         <TextView        
            android:id="@+id/viewSeparat2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="2px" 
            android:background="#DADADA" />


    </RelativeLayout >

</ScrollView >
```

**UPDATE:**

I am getting error when I add the `viewSeparat2` to `ratingBar1`.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: You can put it in a number of places within the <RelativeLayout>, just make sure it's after the definition for ratingBar1 (because you refer to it in the positioning). So what is the actual problem you have here? Does the layout not render? Does it render incorrectly? Or are you trying to add this view programmatically?

Comment: I am getting an error, when I insert another view from an existing hierarchy of views.

Comment: @lordzden Are you trying to add the line below your ratingbar using TextView ?

Comment: @lordzden Please let us know what error you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to do :

```
        android:id="@+id/viewSeparat2"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewSeparator"
```

Comment: I wanted to place the `viewSeparat2` under `ratingBar1`, but I am getting errors when I it.

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:divider="@drawable/seperator"
        android:dividerPadding="12dip"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:padding="10dip"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:tag="image_item_grid_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparator"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textPid"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSellingPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textSellingPrice"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewSeparat2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:text="jhadgjad" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addTOCart"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/itemItem"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_call"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewSeparator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addTOCart"
            android:background="#DADADA" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewSeparat2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparat2"
            android:background="#DADADA" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

[LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) best suits your case, just set orientation property of LinearLayout to vertical and than remove `android:layout_below` from every UI component from xml and add components in the sequence you want to appear in screen. although LinearLayout is slow but in your use case it suits you best`enter code here`

FYI: You may already know, `ScrollView` can have only and only one child(but that child could have its own sub childs)